# How to get the loggedin Users Username and Email in Jasperserver?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I was trying to pass username and email of the loggedin user to a javascript function. I was just wondering how I can grab username and email address. can anyone help me with the object name that can contain those properties?

I tried this way:

```
    var user_object = {
    <c:set var = "loggers_name" value = "<%=((com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.domain.User)com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.getSourceAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getFullName() %>" >

    user:{       
        name: "${loggers_name}",
        email: "${loggers_name}@abc.net" 
    }
    </c:set>
    }
```

Just to use the user fullname, still dont know how to get email though.

This codes are put inside the decorators.jsp

Comment: Please provide any code that you have tried.  This will greatly improve our ability to help.

Answer (score 1):

Email Address:

```
<%= ((com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.domain.User)
   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.
   getSourceAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getEmailAddress() %>
```